# Compute the expected value of the maximum of three exponentially distributed random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that I have $Y_1\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_1), Y_2\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_2), Y_3\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_3),$ and $Y_4\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_4)$ and suppose that I want to calculate the expected value of $X$, $\operatorname{E}(X),$ with $X = \max(Y_1 + Y_2, Y_1 + Y_3, Y_4)$. How do I do so?

Comment: Exponential distributions are closed under addition, with the resulting parameters being the sum of the component distributions parameters. So $Y_1+Y_2 \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)$,  $Y_1+Y_3 \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda_1 + \lambda_3)$, and $Y_4 \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda_4)$. 

So you have the distribution of the maximum of 3 non-iid Exponential random variables.

There exists a theorem giving the order statistics of non-iid random variables which you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem).

Comment: I think my previous comment's approach is overkill, and that there is probably a more efficient way to obtain the expectation; like maybe using the memoryless property of the exponential distribution for example.

If you want to use the previous theorem, there is some computational tricks you can use for special cases. I think this problem fits into the assumptions of Theorem 3.3 [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2768298/pdf/nihms-124957.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

For each $t>0$, $$
\left\{\max(Y_1+Y_2,Y_1+Y_3,Y_4)\leqslant t\right\} = \left\{\max(Y_1+Y_2)\leqslant t\right\}\cap\left\{Y_1+Y_3\leqslant t\right\}\cap \left\{Y_4\leqslant t\right\},
$$
and $Y_1+Y_2$ has density given by convolution
\begin{align}
f_{Y_1+Y_2}(t) &= f_{Y_1}\star f_{Y_2}(t)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R}f_{Y_1}(\tau)f_{Y_2}(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \int_0^t \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1\tau}\lambda_2 e^{-\lambda 2(t-\tau)}\ \mathsf d\tau\\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _2 }{\lambda _2-\lambda _1}\left(e^{-\lambda _1 t}-e^{-\lambda _2 t}\right),& \lambda_1\ne \lambda_2\\
\lambda_1(\lambda_1 t)e^{-\lambda_1 t},& \lambda_1=\lambda_2.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
By symmetry $Y_1+Y_3$ has the same distribution as $Y_1+Y_2$. Let $Z =\max(Y_1+Y_2,Y_1+Y_3,Y_4)$, then for each $t>0$, we have by independence
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P\left(\left\{Y_1+Y_2\leqslant t\right\} \cap \left\{Y_1+Y_3\leqslant t\right\} \cap\left\{Y_4\leqslant t\right\}   \right)\\
&=  \mathbb P(Y_1+Y_2\leqslant t)\mathbb P(Y_1+Y_3\leqslant t)\mathbb P(Y_4\leqslant t)\\
&=\begin{cases}
\int_0^t\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _2 }{\lambda _2-\lambda _1}\left(e^{-\lambda _1 s}-e^{-\lambda _2 s}\right)\ \mathsf ds\cdot\int_0^t\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _3 }{\lambda _3-\lambda _1}\left(e^{-\lambda _1 s}-e^{-\lambda _3 s}\right)\ \mathsf ds\cdot(1-e^{-\lambda_4 t}),& \lambda_1\ne\lambda_2, \lambda_1\ne \lambda_3\\
\int_0^t \lambda_1(\lambda_1 s)e^{-\lambda_1 s}\ \mathsf ds\cdot \int_0^t\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _3 }{\lambda _3-\lambda _1}\left(e^{-\lambda _1 s}-e^{-\lambda _3 s}\right)\ \mathsf ds\cdot(1-e^{-\lambda_4 t})& \lambda_1=\lambda_2, \lambda_1\ne \lambda_3\\
\int_0^t\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _2 }{\lambda _2-\lambda _1}\left(e^{-\lambda _1 s}-e^{-\lambda _2 s}\right)\ \mathsf ds,\cdot \int_0^t\lambda_1(\lambda_1 s)e^{-\lambda_1 s}\ \mathsf dt\cdot(1-e^{-\lambda_4 t})& \lambda_1\ne\lambda_2, \lambda_1= \lambda_3\\
(\int_0^t\lambda_1(\lambda_1 s)e^{-\lambda_1 s}\ \mathsf dt)^2\cdot(1-e^{-\lambda_4 t}) ,& \lambda_1=\lambda_2, \lambda_1= \lambda_3\\
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda _1^2 \lambda _2 \lambda _3 \left(e^{-\lambda _1 t}-e^{-\lambda _2 t}\right) \left(e^{-\lambda _1 t}-e^{-\lambda _3 t}\right) \left(1-e^{-\lambda _4 t}\right)}{\left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2\right) \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _3\right)},& \lambda_1\ne \lambda_2, \lambda_2\ne \lambda_3\\
-\frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _3 \left(e^{-\lambda _1 t}-e^{-\lambda _3 t}\right) \left(1-e^{-\lambda _4 t}\right) \left(1-e^{-\lambda _1 t} \left(\lambda _1 t+1\right)\right)}{\lambda _1-\lambda _3},& \lambda_1=\lambda_2, \lambda_2\ne\lambda_3\\
\left(1-e^{-\lambda _4 t}\right) \left(1-e^{-\lambda _1 t} \left(\lambda _1 t+1\right)\right){}^2,& \lambda_1 = \lambda_2, \lambda_2=\lambda_3.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
For any nonnegative random variable $X$, the mean of $X$ is given by the integral of its survivor function. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Z] &= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2 \left(\frac{2 \lambda _2 \lambda _3}{\lambda _4 \left(\lambda _1+\lambda _4\right) \left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4\right)}+\frac{1}{\lambda _2}-\frac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _3}+\frac{1}{\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _3+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _3+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _3}\right) \lambda _1^2+2 \left(\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _2+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _2}\right) \lambda _3-\frac{\lambda _3}{\lambda _2}+\lambda _2 \left(\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _3}-\frac{1}{\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _3+\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _3+\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _3}\right)\right) \lambda _1-2 \left(\lambda _2+\lambda _3\right)+\frac{3 \lambda _2 \lambda _3}{\lambda _1}}{2 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2\right) \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _3\right)},& \lambda_1\ne\lambda_2, \lambda_2\ne\lambda_3\\
\frac{\left(-\frac{8 \lambda _3}{\lambda _4 \left(\lambda _1+\lambda _4\right) \left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4\right)}-\frac{4}{\left(\lambda _1+\lambda _3\right){}^2}-\frac{4}{\left(\lambda _1+\lambda _4\right){}^2}+\frac{4}{\left(\lambda _1+\lambda _3+\lambda _4\right){}^2}\right) \lambda _1^2+4 \left(\lambda _3 \left(\frac{1}{\left(\lambda _1+\lambda _4\right){}^2}-\frac{1}{\left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4\right){}^2}\right)+\frac{1}{\lambda _3}-\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _3}+\frac{1}{\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _4}-\frac{1}{\lambda _3+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _3+\lambda _4}\right) \lambda _1-\frac{9 \lambda _3}{\lambda _1}+8}{4 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _3\right)} ,& \lambda_1=\lambda_2,\lambda_2\ne\lambda_3\\
\frac{2 \lambda _1^2}{\left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4\right){}^3}+2 \left(\frac{1}{\left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4\right){}^2}-\frac{1}{\left(\lambda _1+\lambda _4\right){}^2}\right) \lambda _1+\frac{11}{4 \lambda _1}+\frac{1}{\lambda _4}-\frac{2}{\lambda _1+\lambda _4}+\frac{1}{2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4},& \lambda_1=\lambda_2, \lambda_2=\lambda_3
\end{cases}
\end{align}
The most interesting case is there the $\lambda_i$ are distinct, in which the expectation of $Z$ is
$$
\tiny\dfrac{2 \left(\dfrac{2 \lambda _2 \lambda _3}{\lambda _4 \left(\lambda _1+\lambda _4\right) \left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _4\right)}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _2}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _3}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _4}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _4}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _3+\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _3+\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _3}\right) \lambda _1^2+2 \left(\left(-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _2+\lambda _4}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _2+\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _2}\right) \lambda _3-\dfrac{\lambda _3}{\lambda _2}+\lambda _2 \left(\dfrac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _3}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _4}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda _3+\lambda _4}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _1+\lambda _3+\lambda _4}-\dfrac{1}{\lambda _3}\right)\right) \lambda _1-2 \left(\lambda _2+\lambda _3\right)+\dfrac{3 \lambda _2 \lambda _3}{\lambda _1}}{2 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2\right) \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _3\right)}.
$$